# Avoiding KeyError when iterating over a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
test = [{'first': '1'}, {'second': '2'}, {'first': '0'}, {'third': '3'}, {'fourth': '4'}]
```

but when I do:

```
stuff = [L['first'] for L in test]
print(stuff)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test_run.py", line 4, in <module>
    stuff = [L['first'] for L in test]
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/test_run.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    stuff = [L['first'] for L in test]
KeyError: 'first'
```

I know I might be doing a silly mistake but any help?

Comment: In your list not all dictionaries has `first` as key

Comment: but in the stuff i only want 'first' do i need to make an if condition for that?

Comment: there is no `TypeError`

Comment: What do you expect as result?

Comment: @MSeifert all the values which have 'first' as key

Comment: @Paul, yes. Do like this - `stuff = [L['first'] for L in test if L.get('first')]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## List comprehension + `if`

If you want all the values, you need to check the dict has the corresponding key first:

```
>>> [d['first'] for d in test if 'first' in d]
['1', '0']
>>> [d['sixth'] for d in test if 'sixth' in d]
[]
```

## Just one value

You could use `next` to get the value corresponding to the first occurence of `'first'`, if you're sure they're at least one dict with a `'first'` value:

```
>>> test = [{'first': '1'}, {'second': '2'}, {'first': '0'}, {'third': '3'}, {'fourth': '4'}]
>>> next(d['first'] for d in test if 'first' in d)
'1'
```

It raises a `StopIteration` otherwise:

```
>>> next(d['sixth'] for d in test if 'sixth' in d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

## Alternative data format

Finally, if you do this operation often, it might be interesting to change the format slightly:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

test = [{'first': '1'}, {'second': '2'}, {'first': '0'}, {'third': '3'}, {'fourth': '4'}]

for d in test:
    for k in d:
        data[k].append(d[k])

print(data)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'second': ['2'], 'fourth': ['4'], 'third': ['3'], 'first': ['1', '0']})
print(data['first'])
# ['1', '0']
print(data['sixth'])
# []
```

The `for` loop is only needed once, the lookup is very fast afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with comprehensions but personally I would simply use a plain for loop - mostly because that way it doesn't **require** the `if` condition. Wrapped as function it could also be easily reused (i.e. for other keys):

```
def get_key(list_of_dicts, key):
    for dct in test:
        try:
            yield dct[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

This is a generator so you can cast it to a list, or use it wherever you would iterate over it:

```
>>> list(get_key(test, 'first'))
['1', '0']
```

Comment: Why would you rely on `try/except` instead of a simple `if` statement? PS: I didn't downvote.

Comment: it's cool too but, don't you think in the matters of database management this method might be a foe? and the list comprehension is more favorable than to this.

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter What kind of database management are we talking about? Wouldn't a `IF` or similar in the query be better than a list-comprehension or a function (after the query)?

Comment: like you have to do large data entries in DMS like Mysql, i'm not abhorring the method but my question is which method will be more convinent.

Comment: @MSeifert: Never heard of it before, at least not for Python. It's usually frowned upon in Ruby, possibly because `rescue` is kinda slow. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter That's a matter of preference. I often use list comprehensions but I also often use such functions. If you reuse it often a function with a good name is sometimes better than a hard-coded comprehension. But in this case the comprehension is probably better. :)

Answer (score 1):

'test' is a list of dictionaries with variable keys. In assumption you only want values from dictionaries with key 'first' returned as list. we can do,

```
test = [{'first': '1'}, {'second': '2'}, {'first': '0'}, {'third': '3'}, {'fourth': '4'}]
stuff = [y['first'] for y in filter(lambda x: 'first' in x, test)]
```

**1)** filter function will only return list dictionaries with key 'first'
 **2)** using that list we can apply list comprehension to get the list of values from dictionaries (with key 'first').

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

L is iterating over the elements of test. When L reaches `{'second': '2'}` `L['first']` will throw a the key error.

A solution to that would be

`[L.get('first') for L in test]`

Accessing dictionary elements via the get method will not throw an exception when a key doesn't exists. Instead, it will return a default value.

You can also pass a custom default value to be returned if key is not found like so:

`[L.get('first','not_found') for L in test]`

If you wish to avoid returning a default value at all, then you have to introduce a conditional inside the list comprehension:

`[L['first'] for L in test if 'first' in test]`